# Is it considered to good to make class awared about it's type?

Tags: java, oop

I have the following interface:

```
public enum AggregatorType{
    DATA_BASE,
    GLOBAL_CACHE,
    //etc
}

public interface DataAggregator<T>{

     public AggregatorType getType();

     public Collection<T> getData();

}
```

My question is about putting different types in the same enumeration. To me, it smells like not a good thing at least (because two separate type put in the same place). But I can't see what potential problems it can lead to. Couldn't you help me understand?

Comment: What benefit would this have over `instanceof`?

Comment: @TobiaTesan No, instanceof is not a solution because I don't know the actual type of the Aggregator.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Would you please describe your use case for this, maybe with an example? I strongly suspect you don't *need* it. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) might be of help :)

Comment: Type enums for objects in OOP normally smell bad; mostly this will better be solve by inheritation or common interfaces.

Comment: @TobiaTesan This is only for splitting different aggregators into the different groups. The aggregators return data and then I'll find their intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Typically using `enum` types is not a good practice to explicitly define the type of a class because in some other part of your code you want must have a control structure (if-else/switch-case) on this type to separate the way of aggregation.

If I were you I would put an `aggregate` method in this interface and I would let the **Polymorphism** mechanism do the magic for me. `DataBaseAggregator` and `CacheAggregator` can be to implementation of this interface to define different behaviors in the aggregation of those data.